# Selenium Java-Checking presence/absence of Weblist elements

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, ui-automation

I need to automate a scenario were-in i need to click on expand all button & check all filters are expanded and then click on collapse all button and check if all filters are collapsed.

The approach i used is to put all the filters in a weblist, get its size & then used assert method to check if its nonempty but for checking the collapse functionality this same approach is failing.

Is there a way to check the visibility or presence of webelements list just like we have isDisplayed() for a single webelement ?

Below is the code for the above logic i tried:

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Expand All")).click();
Thread.sleep(3000);
System.out.println("Clicking on the Expand All option");

Assert.assertFalse(driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("input[type='checkbox']")).isEmpty(),"The Filters are not expanded"); 

int filters_max_size=driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("input[type='checkbox']")).size();

System.out.println("There are total "+filters_max_size+ "filters expanded");

System.out.println("Clicking on the Collapse All option");
Reporter.log("Clicking on the Collapse All option");

driver.findElement(By.id("collapse_all")).click();
Thread.sleep(3000);

Assert.assertTrue(driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("input[type='checkbox']")).isEmpty(),"The Filters are not collapsed"); 
Assert.assertEquals(0, driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("input[type='checkbox']")).,"The Filters are not collapsed");


<a class="refinement_anchor" href="/search?button=search&expand_all=5B%5D=%7B%22s%22%3A%5B%7B%22id%22%3A%22%22%2C%22xPath%22%3A%22%24source_type%22%2C%22logic%22%3A%22OR%22%2C&utf8=%E2%9C%93">
<input id="refinement_214391870" class="flex" type="checkbox" name="refinement_214391870">
<label class="text" for="refinement_214391870">
<div class="text refinement_information">
<span class="label" data-token="{"s":[{"id":"refine_source_type","xPath":"$source_type","logic":"OR","s":[{"n":"Selective"}]}]}" title="Selective"> Selective </span>
<span class="ndocs"> (136,292) </span>
</div>
</label>
</a>
</li>
<li class="text no_children ">
</ul>
<a class="show_all" href="/search/show_all?button=search&id=&q=&types=&utf8=%E2%9C%93&widget_id=refine_source_type">Show all</a>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the size you are getting after collapsing.can u try printing the size after clicking on collapsing

Comment: The size is 86 & it remains same while expanding as well as collapsing

Comment: yes that means they are still attached to dom.you can check isclickable() for each element.Have you tried isDisplayed()

Comment: I am using findelements and not findelement, isDisplayed since i have to check all 86 filters visibility, isDisplayed() doesn't work for Weblists

Comment: in which html tag all those input tags are generating.Can u share the html.In those 86 checkboxes you can check for visibility of some checkboxes because it is one time expansion right

Comment: posted the html in question body

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139826/discussion-between-sai-and-vishal).

Comment: does it gives any error or exception while using to check collapse functionality?

Answer (score 0):

You can try as below:

```
 driver.findElement(By.id("collapse_all")).click();
 Thread.sleep(3000);

WebElement allFilters = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("input[type='checkbox']"));
for(WebElement filter : allFilters) {

 if(filter.isDisplayed()){

   System.out.println(filter.getText() + " is still displayed." );
   break;
 }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can verify the check box is displayed or not by using below code for each checkbox after clicking on collapse all.The below statement will return true if the element is displayed else it will return false(When collapsed in your scenario)

```
elem.isDisplayed()
```